# What can perfectly convert EPUB to PDF?

Tags: windows, pdf, document-converter, epub

For Windows 8.1 and also Windows 10, what can reproduce EPUB files as a PDF, with no changes and loss of quality?

I ask NOT about Calibre and ePub Converter, which can transform an EPUB file into a PDF, but which uselessly disfigured the original EPUB's font, format, and structure. Specifically, the text in the PDF becomes disorganised; one original paragraph (on the original page) is chaotically split into different pages. All text layout and formatting are lost: paragraphs are compressed together, headers shrink in size to cease its appearance as a header, etc.

Comment: **Nothing** can perfectly _convert ePub to PDF_, as a PDF is a static visual presentation, while an ePub book is dynamic in its presentation. The font and format, at least, is left up to the reader software. The structure is given, but how it is presented can be left somewhat to the presentation software. So please clarify why Calibre and ePub converter doesn't work for you, and what you perceive as the perfect conversion.

Comment: @holroy Thanks. I clarified above in my OP. Better?

Answer (score 13):

I personally have always had good results from [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) but about the only thing that I can think of that will 100% of the time accurately reproduce the onscreen content of an eBook in a PDF file is to print to a PDF file using one of the many print to PDF drivers available - *I will not try to recommend one as I do not know which OS you are on.*

Pandoc is free & cross platform so has to be worth a try.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I elucidated which OP I use in my OP.

Comment: pandoc was such a waste of time, I had to download a TeX distribution to get pdflatex.exe and when I did, it simply said `Error producing PDF.` while converting using `pandoc -o out.pdf book.epub`

Comment: pandoc sounded interesting in theory but having to download livetex (>3GB) or miktex (throws error 'tex capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3178236]') is simply unbearable, when all you want is pdflatex.exe and have it generate a pdf from an epub. I ended up using ebook-convert.exe which is a command line interface already shipped with calibre.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LEADTOOLS Document SDK technology in your application.
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/document
You can leverage the DocumentConverter class to convert any LEADTOOLS supported file format to any other LEADTOOLS supported file format (i.e. ePUB to PDF).

**DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit.**

Here is some sample code:

using (DocumentConverter _converter = new DocumentConverter())
{
string inputEPUB = @"FILE PATH TO INPUT ePUB";
string outputPDF = @"FILE PATH TO OUTPUT PDF";

```
DocumentFormat format = DocumentFormat.Pdf;
var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(inputEPUB, outputPDF, format);

var job = _converter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
_converter.Jobs.RunJob(job);

if (job.Status == DocumentConverterJobStatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Errors", job.Status);
    foreach (var error in job.Errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0} at {1}: {2}", error.Operation, error.InputDocumentPageNumber, error.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You may try [PDFMate eBook Converter](http://www.pdfmate.com/ebook-converter-professional.html). It seems to be a new program, but works well for me right now.

You can visit the official website of PDFMate at www.pdfmate.com. Some of its programs are free. PDFMate eBook Converter seems to be a new program as I didn't see it months ago. I downloaded the program the other day to convert epub to pdf & mobi, worked okay for me.

Comment: Please provide a link to the mentioned product. Any affiliation with PDFMate ? if so please mention.

Comment: You can visit the official website of PDFMate at www.pdfmate.com. Some of its' programs are free. PDFMate eBook Converter seems to be a new program as I didn't see it months ago. I downloaded the program the other day to convert epub to pdf & mobi, worked okay for me.

Comment: @JoeGromny: Please add this info into the body of your answer. Do you have any affiliation with PDFMate? Thanks!